# cURL response not showing body of XML

Tags: shell-script, curl, xml

I'm trying to write a bash script that makes it easier to use `rtmpdump` for downloading Flash lecture videos. I've gotten pretty much everything else to work except for using cURL to grab the necessary mp4 URL from the XML page.

When I run the following command in my terminal, I get what I want:

```
curl -s http://amps-web.amps.ms.mit.edu/courses/6/6.046/2017spring/L01/MIT-6.046-lec-mit-0000-2017feb09-1103-L01/settings-flash.xml | grep "rtmp:"
```

yields:

```
rtmp://flashsvr1.amps.ms.mit.edu/6.046/mp4:2017spring/MIT-6.046-lec-mit-0000-2017feb09-1103-L01.mp4</url>
```

(I'm aware of the trailing header, it's taken care of in my bash script)

However, when I try to run the same command in my bash script and save the output to a variable, I get nothing. Running just `xml=$(curl -s $url)` and echoing that out results in a bunch of (but not all) headers, nothing else:

```
<camera id="2" cameraX="960" cameraY="0" thumbnailX="960" thumbnailY="0" name="CAM2" selectedName="LIVE 2 
<camera id="3" cameraX="0" cameraY="540" thumbnailX="0" thumbnailY="540" name="CAM3" selectedName="LIVE 3 
<camera id="4" cameraX="960" cameraY="540" thumbnailX="960" thumbnailY="540" name="CAM4" selectedName="LI 
<fullscreenOutButtonImageOver>fallback/assets/btn_fullscreenOff_selected.png</fullscreenOutButtonImageOve 
<fullscreenOutButtonImageDown>fallback/assets/btn_fullscreenOff_selected.png</fullscreenOutButtonImageDow 
<communityRealOutButtonImageNormal>fallback/assets/buttons/community_selected_up.png</communityRealOutBut 
<communityRealOutButtonImageOver>fallback/assets/buttons/community_over.png</communityRealOutButtonImageO 
<communityRealOutButtonImageDown>fallback/assets/buttons/community_down.png</communityRealOutButtonImageD 
<thumbspositionTopButtonImageNormal>fallback/assets/btn_thumbnailPositionTop.png</thumbspositionTopButton 
<thumbspositionBottomButtonImageNormal>fallback/assets/btn_thumbnailPositionBottom.png</thumbspositionBot 
</settings>ge>fallback/assets/affiche.png</landingImage>>ng</thumbnailActive>Progress>geDown>Down>
```

Does anyone know what might be happening with this? It's quite frustrating. Thanks!

Comment: your example `xml=$(curl -s $url)` does not have the `grep` that the first command does...?

Comment: Yeah, that's because if it did have the `grep` section, nothing would print because nothing would be matched. The reason I displayed the results of the isolated curl is to show from where the problem stems. Showing a blank readout wouldn't give as much info as the curl readout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data has carriage-returns in it. Filter them out:

```
curl ... | tr -d '\r'
```

Also, quote your variable when you echo it:

```
$ echo "$xml"
```

Or even better:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$xml"
```

Quoting prevents word-splitting. Word-splitting happen on all unquoted variables on the command line and involves splitting them line into words based on the value of `$IFS`. `$IFS` is by default a tab-character and a space-character and a new-line character.

See "Word Splitting" or "Field Splitting" in the manual for your shell.

Comment: Can you explain the difference in behavior between echo-ing a variable with or without quotes?

Comment: @MIT_noob Updated.